# ASP.net application detours off to the IIS.net web page after login

Tags: asp.net

I have developed an asp application in Visual Studio and have installed it on a server machine. This is an intranet application, meant only for clients in the office network.  It runs under IIS on the server machine.

The application works fine in my development environment and has been installed and was in limited use by a few users, and worked fine there as well. When started, the application displays a sign on/password screen, then continues on to the default page (basically, a main menu type page.)

As I'm expanding the user base to include the rest of the people in the office, I have found that, inexplicably (to me) on some of the machines the program displays the sign on/password screen, but instead of continuing on to the default page it shows the IIS.net Welcome page (the word 'welcome' displayed in many different languages), then goes to the IIS.net default web page.

I'm at a loss for where to look to solve the problem. I don't know what code I could include to look for an error. If I had to guess, I would think this was a problem somewhere on the client machines, but I don't know for sure, and I don't know where to look.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: probably you have some redirects from http to https or vise versa pages that you did not have setup on iis

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I don't know how to use it to help me solve the problem.

Comment: You can setup on IIS the https as well to bind on the same site - if you use plex, the latest version check and disable inside the plex the https always option - and fix the https binding

Comment: Is this a client-side or a server-side setup? Because remember, I said that it is already working for some users, so it wouldn't make sense to me that it's a server issue. (No idea what plex is, so I'm assuming that's a 'no'.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, after much hunting around, I came up with not necessarily the solution to my problem, but at least a work-around.

I am using Forms Authentication. In my web.config file is the following:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="CustCookie" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30" path="/"/>
</authentication>
```

I took the logic for the login page from something I read somewhere, and have this statement in my login program:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet)
```

where the login screen has a UserName text box and a box to check for 'Remember Me' (which I have disabled because I didn't want a Remember Me option right now.)

I put in some code to allow me to see what was happening:

Dim m_url As String = FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(RptObj.User.UserName, False)

and found that for some users the url was coming back fine while for others all I got was '/', which was causing it to reroute to the IIS main page. I added a 'defaultUrl="~/default.aspx"' to my web.config forms line, but that didn't solve it, so I added the following to my login program:

```
            Dim m_url As String = FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(RptObj.User.UserName, False)
            If m_url = "/" Then
                Server.Transfer("~/default.aspx")
            Else
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet)
            End If
```

Not a very elegant way to get the job done in my mind, but it worked.